# Cleaning out a workspace and setting a new mapping to the client

Tags: perforce

I was using Perforce to check some code in, into a workspace on the server. As luck would have it, things got into a mess.

How can I easily delete everything on my project, on the server, and set a new mapping to the project on the client (my dev machine)?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to permanently remove all the code that's on the server? And then make a second attempt (same location?) using the same clientspec?

Comment: Yep that is what I am trying to do. What is a clientspec btw?

Comment: Clientspec is the original name that Perforce had for workspace... sorry, old habits die hard.

Answer (score 3):

The [obliterate](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/obliterate.html) command (only available to users with super access) is used to permanently remove files from Perforce.  Be aware that when you obliterate a file, it's like it never existed.  All the revision history will be gone.  If you really, **really** want to start over, then you should obliterate the files, otherwise you can just [delete](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/delete.html) them (which will maintain the revision history).

Once the files have been obliterated/deleted, you should just be able to re-add the new files to the depot in the same location.  I know that deleting the files will also remove them from your workspace, but it's been a while since I've obliterated anything, so I don't remember what happens there.  If obliterating *does* leave the files on your computer, you can just delete them.

Comment: Looks like I need to do a delete. I am a bit confused about "but are not deleted from the depot until the corresponding changelist is sent to the server with p4 submit.". Does this mean that when everything is deleted, and I delete the corresponding files on my machine and replace them and submit, everything will work? Also, what would be the command to delete an entire dir and its subdirs/files?

Comment: Deleting files opens them for delete in a changelist, which you then submit to complete the action (at which point they will also be removed from your local workspace). You can delete an entire directory in P4V by right clicking on the directory and picking "Mark for delete." You can do this from the command line by typing `p4 delete //path/to/delete/...`